# Can't run vagrant provision for Laravel Homestead Vagrant

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead, parallels

- I refer to Laravel's official documentation to install Homestead.
- When I run the `vagrant reload --provision` , I get the error message shown below.
- I found my mac `.ssh` directory, it is empty.
- But `Homestead.yaml` includes this line `authorize: ~ / .ssh / id_rsa.pub`, I do not understand what is wrong.

[image: error screenshot]

[image: Homestead.yaml]

[image: it says parallels is ok]

Comment: Noticed that you use provider: parallels and not virtualbox. Read here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-can-i-run-homestead-with-parallels

Comment: Right, but  it told me Parallels is ok when I add the homestead box to vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I thought that keys where created when you add the homestead box to vagrant.

Anyway, the error says what the problem is. You don't have a ssh key so you need to create a new.

Enter your home directory (on your mac) and run this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "you@yourmail.com"
```

Then check directory: ~/.ssh/ so files are created and have the same name as referenced in Homestead.yaml

Comment: Maybe it's because the parallels, After running your command, the error becomes `The provider 'parallels' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'homestead-7'. Please use a provider that exists.`

Comment: I don't know parallels unfortunately, but googling gave this that might be a clue "http://kb.parallels.com/en/122864". Please note that this error is not the same that you posted as question though.